# How to concatenate in for loop?

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array, concatenation, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to concatenate `k`, `counter`, and in data `temp_reg`, but the resultant value does not concatenate the values in `k` array.  But, the concatenation of `counter` and in data works fine.  Is there something wrong with my approach?

Here is my code:

```
module Concatenation #(
    parameter NUM_VALS = 8,
    parameter SIZE     = 8
)(  input  wire rst,
    input  wire clk,
    input  wire [NUM_VALS-1:0] k,
    input  wire [NUM_VALS*SIZE-1:0] in,
    output reg  [NUM_VALS*SIZE-1:0] out
);
    reg [2:0] count;
    reg [SIZE + 3:0] temp_reg [1:NUM_VALS];

    always @* begin
    if(~rst) begin
        count = 7;
    end
    else begin
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i = i + 1) begin
            temp_reg[i+1] = {k[i], count-i, in[i*SIZE +: SIZE]};
        end
    end
    end

endmodule
```

for example:

```
k = [101]
counter = 7;
in = [00100010_00100010_00100010]
```

should result in

```
in = [111100100010
      011000100010
      110100100010]
```

but instead I get

```
in = [011100100010
      011000100010
      010100100010]
```

i.e. none of the bits in `k` are concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

As Serge pointed out `count -i` results in a 32bit value, which pushes the index of `k` beyond the 12bit range.

To fix it, you can cast it into a 3bit value ([IEEE1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § 6.24.1 *Cast operator*):

```
temp_reg[i+1] = {k[i], 3'(count-i), in[i*SIZE +: SIZE]};
```

Or you can assign specific slices of `temp_reg` ([IEEE1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § 11.5.1 *Vector bit-select and part-select addressing*). For example:

```
temp_reg[i+1][SIZE+3] = k[i];
temp_reg[i+1][SIZE +: 3] = count-i;
temp_reg[i+1][0 +: SIZE] = in[i*SIZE +: SIZE]};
```

The cast strategy only works with SystemVerilog. The slice strategy is backward compatible with Verilog(IEEE1364-2001 and newer).